# »Chäa«: Mehrzahl von »Chaos«?

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich hielt das Wort »Chaos« bisher für ein Wort, das es nur im Singular, nicht aber im Plural gibt. Der Fachbegriff für so etwas ist *Singularetantum*, und in dem [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularetantum), der sich damit befasst, wird das Wort *»Chaos«* sogar als eines von mehreren Beispielen genannt.

In [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chaos) steht explizit:

> Cha·os, *kein Plural*

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Chaos) ist etwas weniger explizit, aber dennoch unmissverständlich. Bei den Beugungsformen von *Chaos* listet er nur die Singularformen auf. Ein Plural wird nicht erwähnt.

Nun lese ich aber gerade das Buch

> **Denksport DEUTSCH**
>   *Wer hat bloß **die** Gabel zur Frau und **den** Löffel zum Mann gemacht?*
>
> von Daniel Scholten
>   dtv, September 2016
>   978-3-423-26134-0

Dort geht es im Kapitel *»Der Yonis und das Lingam«* um das System der grammatischen Geschlechter, das auch schon im Altgriechischen, im Rigveda und im Sanskrit ebenso unlogisch war wie im modernen Neuhochdeutsch. Auf Seite 33 bis 34 steht dann dieser Absatz:

> Nicht nur gleich schlimm im Ausmaß, sondern auch von gleicher Beschaffenheit: *die Tür, die thýra, die dvar.* So verblüffend gleich ist sie, dass diese ***Chäa*** - jetzt kennen Sie endlich die Mehrzahl von *Chaos*, die braucht man ja sonst kaum - nie und nimmer unabhängig voneinander entstanden sein können. Sie sind Nachkommen eines einzigen Urchaos.

Der Autor [Daniel Scholten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Scholten) behauptet also ganz ausdrücklich, und das in einem Buch, das sich der deutschen Sprache und ihren Besonderheiten widmet, dass es vom *Chaos* doch eine Mehrzahl gäbe, und er gibt diese Pluralform auch bekannt.

Wer hat denn nun recht? Wikipedia, Wiktionary und Duden? Oder Daniel Scholten?

Und falls Herr Scholten recht haben sollte: Warum nicht *Chaose*, *Chaen* oder meinetwegen *Chaä*? Warum sind ein Chaos und ein anders Chaos zusammen zwei ***Chäa***?

Comment: Bei [der Gesellschaft zur Stärkung schwacher Verben](https://verben.texttheater.net/Plurale) hat er das auf jeden Fall nicht abgeguckt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Mir war gar nicht bewusst, dass sich die Verbenstärker auch mit Substantiven befassen.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Daniel Scholten hat wohl versucht, aus der altgriechischen Deklination von χάος (*chaos*) einen im Deutschen bizarr aussehenden Plural zu bilden.

Der Wortstamm von χάος (Nominativ Singular) lautet in verschiedenen altgriechischen Dialekten χαε- (*chae-*), die Pluralendung wäre -α (*-a*). Der Plural (falls es tatsächlich einen geben sollte) müsste also χαεα lauten, was in der Umschrift *chaea* wäre.

Scholten hat das *-ae-* gemäß deutscher Gepflogenheiten in ein *-ä-* abgewandelt, so dass sich die bizarre Form *Chäa* ergibt. Hier handelt er analog zur Wiedergabe lateinischer Wörter, bei denen der Diphthong *ae* im Deutschen gerne mit dem Umlaut *ä* wiedergegeben wird, vgl. etwa lat. *Caesar* und dt. *Cäsar*.

Der Grund liegt darin, dass sich der Lautwert von *ae*, der noch zu Caesars Zeiten eher einem *ai* (wie in dt. *Mai*) entsprach, schon in der Antike zu einem offenen *e* gewandelt hat, das sich wie ein deutsches *ä* angehört haben dürfte.

Ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob dies bei einem altgriechischen αε (*ae*) auch korrekt ist. Dem lateinischen *ae* entspricht im Griechischen der Diphthong αι (*ai*), sodass Griechen in der Antike z.B. *Caesar* als Καισαρ (*Kaisar*) wiedergaben. Griechische Fremdwörter mit einem αι (*ai*) werden deshalb, weil sie meist über den Umweg über das Lateinische ins Deutsche kamen, mit *ä* geschrieben, z.B. gr. σφαιρα > lat. *sphaera* > dt. Sphäre.

Entsprechend schreiben wir griechisches αι (*ai*) auch dann als *ä*, wenn es keine lateinische Zwischenform gibt. Das ist nicht zuletzt auch dadurch gerechtfertigt, da das neugriechische αι (*ai*) ebenfalls fast wie ein deutsches *ä* gesprochen wird.

Griechisches αε (*ae*) scheint mir aber kein Diphthong gewesen zu sein, sondern tatsächlich zwei unabhängige Vokale repräsentiert zu haben, weshalb die Pluralform eher *cha-e-a* ausgesprochen werden müsste. Statt Scholtens *Chäa* würde ich also eher *Chaea* als korrekte Pluralform ansehen (die aber im Deutschen wohl doch die meisten Leser als *Chäa* aussprechen würden).

Insofern nehme ich an, dass Scholten wohl ein Fehler, evtl. eine Verwechslung mit dem Lateinischen, unterlaufen ist (sofern er nicht mehr weiß als ich).

*EDIT nach dem Verweis von Hubert Schölnast auf [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/χάος](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%AC%CE%BF%CF%82):*

Im attischen Dialekt des Altgriechischen, das für die griechische Klassik (Platon, Aristoteles usw.) bestimmend wurde, ist das -ε- (*-e-) mit der Endung -α zu -η (offenes *e*, klingt wie der Umlaut *ä*) verschmolzen, so dass der Nominativ Plural χάη (*chae*) lautet.

Vielleicht ist Scholtens falsche Form *Chäa* durch einen simplen Tippfehler entstanden: Er wollte statt *Chae* lieber *Chaä* schreiben, damit der Leser nicht *Chae* fälschlich wie *chä* ausspricht, und dabei hat er unwillkürlich *a* und *ä* vertauscht.

Allerdings wird das griechische -η- im Deutschen üblicherweise als *e* wiedergegeben, *ä* ist eher unüblich, obwohl das dem klassischen Lautwert besser entspricht, da wir eher dazu neigen, das *e* geschlossen -- und lang, wie z.B. in *S**ee**le* -- zu sprechen. Meine Buchstabendreher-Hypothese funktioniert daher nur, wenn Scholten grundsätzlich gegen die Konvention verstößt, was ich nicht weiß.

Auf [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/χάος](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%AC%CE%BF%CF%82) werden zudem noch die Pluralformen χάοι (*chaoi*) und χάα (*chaa*) erwähnt. Die gehören aber nicht zum Substantiv χάος, sondern zu einem zufällig homophonen Adjektiv χάος (*chaos*), das selten ist und nur eine Nebenform von χά**ϊ**ος (*cha**i**os*) darstellt. Es bedeutetet so viel wie 'echt' oder 'wahr' und hat mit dem hier diskutierten Chaos nichts zu tun.

*EDIT Ende*

Übrigens bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob es im Altgriechischen wirklich einen Plural von χάος gegeben hat, mir persönlich ist jedenfalls noch nie einer untergekommen.

Daniel Scholten will den Leser wohl eher durch eine Ausreizung der denkbaren sprachlichen Möglichkeiten überraschen, unterhalten und zum Nachdenken über Sprache anregen. Denksport eben...

Comment: Wie schön, dass sich so schnell jemand findet, der in den verschiedenen altgriechischen Dialekten bewandert ist!

Comment: Hey, willkommen auf dem Stack zur deutschen Sprache :) Wenn Du Zeit und Lust hast, kannst Du die [tour] und das [help] besuchen, um mehr über die Funktionen und Feinheiten der Sprache zu erfahren. Mit Deiner Antwort hast Du zudem bereits genügend magische EInhornpunkte eingespielt, um am [chat] teilnehmen zu können. Schönen Abend noch :)

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob Scholten überraschen oder zum Nachdenken anregen will. Kommt mir mehr vor wie ein Klugsch...

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%AC%CE%BF%CF%82) gibt mir das (regelnäßige) χάη als Plural von χάος. Zumindest bei Wörtern, die auf den Wortstamm aer- gebildet sind, wird im deutschen ein griechisches αε als ae übernommen, nicht als ä, etwa in Aeronaut. (Wobei ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob das nicht womöglich in der Form aus dem Italienischen übernommen ist.)

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort, vielen Dank! Auf https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/χάος finde ich aber gleich mehrere verschiedene Pluralformen für χάος, nämlich χάεᾰ, χάη, χάοι und χάα (alle: Nominativ)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Den Klugscheißer-Eindruck habe ich auch. Und wäre es kein geschriebener Text, sondern eine gesprochene Rede, würde ich (zumindest nach den ersten 80 Seiten) sagen: Scholten hört sich gerne selbst reden. Aber das ist Kritik, die nur die Verpackung betrifft. Den Inhalt hingegen halte ich für sehr lehrreich. Scholten hat mir mit seinem Buch zu einer ganze Reihe von Aha-Erlebnissen verholfen, da will ich ihm seine sprachliche Eitelkeit gerne nachsehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: der bei wiktionary angegebene Plural χάοι ist die maskuline/feminine Endung des homonymen Adjektivs χάος 'echt', 'wahr', das mit dem Substantiv χάος selbst nichts zu tun hat. χάα ist Neutrum Plural dieses Adjektivs, das habe ich in meiner Antwort verwechselt und die Pluralform χάη des Substantivs vergessen. Ich werde es editieren.

Answer (score 5):

Wieso man annimmt, dass man, wenn man *ein* Wort aus einer fremden Sprache entlehnt, gleich **alle Bildungen** mit ausleihen müsste, ist mir ein Rätsel (wahrscheinlich, weil man sonst ein Buch nicht vollkriegt - Einer weiteren Aussage über diese Art von Buch enthalte ich mich hier).

Im Lateinischen (*chaos* ist bei mir Latein, kein Altgriechisch - Ich denke, wir haben uns hier eher das lateinische Lehnwort entlehnt) mag es die Mehrzahl (*chaa*) wohl geben - Im Deutschen aber nicht.

Anderes aktuelles Beispiel in anderer Sprache:

Im Deutschen gibt es *Angst* und *Ängste*, die Briten haben aber beschlossen, von uns nicht gleich alle *Ängste* zu nehmen - [Eine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/angst) reicht ihnen, und das Wort hat im Englischen daher keinen Plural (Zum Ausgleich scheint das Englische interessanterweise dafür aber mehr als ein [Chaos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chaos) zu kennen, dafür haben sie einen Plural).

Comment: Lehnwörter, die mit *-os* enden, sind fast immer griechisch (*Mythos, Kosmos, Pathos*). So ist das auch bei Chaos: χάος *(cháos)* ist ein altgriechisches Wort und heißt auf deutsch: *leerer Raum, Luftraum, Kluft*. Das deutsche Wort *Gas* ist auch davon abgeleitet. Der altgriechische Plural von χάος ist übrigens χάοι *(cháoi)*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das stimmt und das weiß ich. *Chaos* ist aber schon ein Lehnwort, das die Römer von den Griechen übernommen haben. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass wir die lateinische Vokabel (und nicht die gleiche griechische) übernommen haben, ist groß, nachdem das Wort wohl durch die Bibelübersetzung bei uns angekommen ist, die auch aus dem Lateinischen stammt.

Comment: Wiktionary scheint meiner Meinung zu sein (oder gibt uns beiden recht): https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chaos

Comment: Und DWDS: "Es erscheint zuerst als unveränderte Wiedergabe von lat. chaos (Luk. 16, 26),..."

Comment: Wiktionary schreibt aber auch im selben Satz: »... aus dem mittelenglischen chaos ...«. Das Wort scheint in den deutschen Wortschatz also aus dem Englischen gekommen zu sein. Dorthin ist es aber möglicherweise nicht direkt aus Latein gekommen, sondern aus dem Französischen. Die Griechen haben das Wort aber auch nicht selbst erfunden. Es gibt nämlich das deutlich ältere urindogermanische (nach neuerer Diktion *protoindoeuropäische*) Wort **gheu-*, das sich zum altgriechischen *khaos* gewandelt hat.

Comment: Wir haben also: Urindogermanisch - Altgriechisch - Latein - (möglicherweise Französisch) - Englisch - Deutsch. Da fällt es schwer zu argumentieren, das Wort wäre ein lateinisches Wort.

Comment: Da hat Scholten in einem Text über Sprache an einer Stelle Spaß mit der Sprache, und ihr müsst alles gleich bierernst nehmen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du kuckst beim *englischen* Chaos. Die hatten keinen Luther. Dass das Wort *ganz ursprünglich* aus dem Griechischen stammt, ist unbestritten. Die Frage ist nur, woher wir es haben.

Comment: @CarstenS Da ist dir möglicherweise entgangen, dass meine Antwort *nicht ganz bierernst* (aber wohl hoffentlich trotzdem "richtig") formuliert ist...

Comment: Sorry, aber Dein erster Absatz schien mir zu implizieren, dass Scholten das völlig ernst und ohne Einschränkung meint.

Comment: @CarstenS Das liegt daran, dass ich solche Bücher nicht (und auch Herrn Sick's Kolumne z.B. nicht) mag. Daniel Scholten wäre möglicherweise der erste, der drüberherziehen würde, wenn jemand das tatsächlich so sagen würde...

Comment: Fair enough. In der Tat ist er mir oft zu absolut in seinen Aussagen. Ich hätte ich trotzdem nicht gleich mit Sick verglichen ;)

Comment: @CarstenS Das war ja auch kein Vergleich ;) Ich mag nur beider Elaborate nicht (oder nicht alles davon)

Comment: Ich kannte Scholten vorher nicht. Mein Eindruck: Er ist eitel, aber auch wissend. Wenn man bereit ist, Federboa und Rüschenschirmchen zu ignorieren, kann man trotzdem einiges über die deutsche Sprache lernen. Ich kann verstehen, dass sich viele mit ihm schwer tun, und ich bin auch alles andere als begeistert von seinem Stil, aber ich finde den Inhalt viel zu interessant, um das Buch wegzulegen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Federboa und Rüschenschirmchen" hat ein +1 verdient

Answer (score 2):

χάος is a third-declension neuter noun. The genitive singular is χάεος, or contracted χάους. Τhe nominative plural (if it exists) would be χάεα or χάη (definitely not “χάοι”!). In Greek and Latin loanwords the German “ä” stands for Greek αι, or Latin ae, never for Greek disyllabic άε. Thus “chäa” is definitely wrong.

http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dxa%2Fos1

Comment: Yes, ΝΑΙΧΙ! ΧΑΗ would be the correct form in Attic dialect, if a plural existed. XAOI can be absolutely excluded. XAEA would probably occur in other dialects, that are more analytic with respect to the endings. Βut so far I have not found any references in plural. I checked some modern Greek declension tables for Ancient Greek, which mark it as plurale tantum.